# Use $wpdb->get_results with filter based on array

Tags: query, post-meta, wpdb

I need to filter my SQL query (in a plugin) based on an array of meta_values.

I have CPT-A which is related to CPT-B.

I am keeping an array of CPT-A ids in `meta_key` **afz_entry_tags** of CPT-B

I need to get all the `post_title` from CPT-A posts where the ids are in the array of the CPT-B meta.

Getting the values:

```
$tags = get_post_meta( $postid, 'afz_entry_tags', true );
```

The following does NOT work but i needed to show what i want to do.

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 
    $wpdb->prepare( "select post_title from $wpdb->posts
    where id in (%s) and post_type = %s and post_status = %s ", $tags, 'e4afz_tag_cpt' ,'publish' ));
```

Comment: "based on an array of meta_values" doesn't completely explain what you want to achieve. How are values stored (is it single key with multiple values or array of value)? What filter do you want precisely (for combination of all values or any single value)?

Comment: share the complete code

Comment: Added explanation